# How to split a string with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to know if I can split a string simply in angularJS.
I have my

```
 $scope.test = "test1,test2";
```

in my controller and in my view,
I wanted to do something like that

```
{{test[0] | split(',')}}
{{test[1] | split(',')}}
```

I've seen a lot thing about input and ng-change calling a function in the controller that split the string or something with ng-list but nothing works in my case.

thx to all.

Comment: what should the `{{}}` expression output as the result of the split? `{{}}` expressions are treated as strings, while i'm guessing you want `split` to return an array

Comment: Can't you use plain JavaScript to split the String? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: [better article on String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), sorry Lukas.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You may want to wrap that functionality up into a filter, this way you don't have to put the mySplit function in all of your controllers. For example

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .filter('split', function() {
        return function(input, splitChar, splitIndex) {
            // do some bounds checking here to ensure it has that index
            return input.split(splitChar)[splitIndex];
        }
    });
```

From here, you can use a filter as you originally intended

```
{{test | split:',':0}}
{{test | split:',':0}}
```

More info at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter (thanks ross)

Plunkr @ http://plnkr.co/edit/NA4UeL

Comment: The arguments need to be passed ':'-delimited: `{{ expression | filter:argument1:argument2:... }}`, so in this case: `{{test | split:",":0 }}`. [New docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). I'm guessing this changed sometime in the past 6 months

Answer (score 51):

Thx guys, I finally found the solution, a really basic one..
In my controller I have

```
$scope.mySplit = function(string, nb) {
    var array = string.split(',');
    return array[nb];
}
```

and in my view

```
{{mySplit(string,0)}}
```

Comment: Congratulations on finding a solution by yourself. You should consider to accecpt your own answer.

Comment: this would be better handled by creating a custom filter - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: It's better to use a filter, like in the above answer

Answer (score 36):

You can try something like this:

```
$scope.test = "test1,test2";
{{test.split(',')[0]}}
```

now you will get "**test1**" while you try `{{test.split(',')[0]}}`

and you will get "**test2**" while you try `{{test.split(',')[1]}}`

here is my plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jaXOrZX9UO9kmdRMImdN?p=preview

Comment: It's pretty clear veljasije. Instead of using directive or function he used the split method for the string object directly in the view. KISS.

Comment: @veljasije just go and the link , i did it clearly on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/jaXOrZX9UO9kmdRMImdN?p=preview

Comment: Now I feel dumb googling for it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$scope.testdata = [{ 'name': 'name,id' }, {'name':'someName,someId'}]
$scope.array= [];
angular.forEach($scope.testdata, function (value, key) {
    $scope.array.push({ 'name': value.name.split(',')[0], 'id': value.name.split(',')[1] });
});
console.log($scope.array)
```

This way you can save the data for later use and acces it by using an ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">{{item.name}}{{item.id}}</div>
```

I hope this helped someone, 
Plunker link: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N9xmLtJ9bgD3zoatT3CW?p=preview)
All credits go to @jwpfox and @Mohideen ibn Mohammed from the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest one for AngularJS

{{test.split('T')[0]}}