# How to split string using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split

I am new in angular js.

my array -

```
"cards":[
"xxx Bank Credit Card",
"yyy Bank Debit Card"
],
```

what i am tring get only xxx adn yyy or Credit and Debit from the string .I am using angular js 1.2.23 .

Comment: You can do by creating custom filter..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string with angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448100/how-to-split-a-string-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .filter('split', function() {
        return function(input, splitChar, splitIndex) {
            // do some bounds checking here to ensure it has that index
            return input.split(splitChar)[splitIndex];
        }
    });
```

Use in view like

```
{{test | split(',',0)}}
```

Ref - [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448100/how-to-split-a-string-with-angularjs)

Comment: if I have to add this split function on `ng-model` instead of {{ }}  expression, then how to add filter on ng-model parameter

Comment: You can not use filter with `ng-model`. I think you want to apply filter on your ng-model value which you can achieve with custom `$watch` on that model.

Comment: ya I can not use it on ng-model..... but my question is how to use it on ng-model value? in controller? using $filter? or can we use?

Answer (score 0):

You  can even use default Filter of Angular Js " limitTo() " . it is very helpful but not a splitter , 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

in your case you can use it like 
{{cards[0] | limitTo(3) }} =xxx