# splitting ng-repeat into 2 rows and repeating the same for all the data (using bootstrap grids)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, frontend

Need to create this pattern in html dynamically 
ie. 
if I repeat `var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];`

I need to get this output using angularjs and bootstrap grid

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8 9 10
11 12
```

basic structure i can think of is this, with some repeat logic.

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in itemsList">
  <div class="group">
    <!-- need to repeat this pattern as long as there is data  -->
    <div class="row two-element-row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        {{item}}
        <!-- need 2 elements here -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row three-element-row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        {{item}}
        <!-- need next 3 elements here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I dont want to model the data in JS preferably. 
I have a simple logic to create chunks of data of the incoming data and divide it into this pattern and then render the data, but that isnt what i want to do. 
Is there any pure angular way to do this? 
If there is any quick fix too , it would be great!

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448100/how-to-split-a-string-with-angularjs

Comment: @Dev-One unfortunately no. This is gonna require some further processing as i dont have a finite set of data. I cant manage each row individually. 
_Thanks for showing me a cool new way to handle ng repeat though!_

Comment: I am not sure if angular is capable of handling split in the way you want. What you probably can do is to repeat items in a table/grid and use CSS to manage size of the alternating rows.

Comment: Yeah that seems a viable option. But i just cant manage to come up with a robust logic for this pattern. (See the pattern i added)