# How to split the strings in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to split a string and get the string in two parts.

for example:

```
www.medicoshere.com/register.html?23457cedlske234cd
```

i wish to split the string in the above url and store the string that is after the ? to a variable. How can i do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string with angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17448100/4944490)

Comment: oops sorry......! But that is using filter i need it in controller

Comment: there are so many answers available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "www.medicoshere.com/register.html?23457cedlske234cd";
var res = str.split("?");
var value = res.slice(-1).pop(); // it will give 23457cedlske234cd
```

Comment: Perfectly short and simple.

Comment: @NivasDhina Mine is shorter ;)

Comment: Thanks @NivasDhina

Comment: @Chrillewoodz but in your case if string may like `www.medicoshere.com?register.html?23457cedlske234cd` then OP need to read index 2 then. Am I right ? It's just an example my concern was if there might be 2 `?` then indexing will differ.

Comment: True, but why would you have two `?`? Then it would be `?` followed by additional parameters as `&`.

Comment: I never bothered what it does.... i just used your snippets.... Thanks for both of you to take time and type an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
var newString = 'www.medicoshere.com/register.html?23457cedlske234cd'.split('?')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split` to go from strings to an array of the split substrings:

```
var s = "one, two, three, four, five"
s.split(", ");  // ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

You can then access the individual parts with `s[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
$scope.string = "www.medicoshere.com/register.html?23457cedlske234cd";
$scope.s = $scope.string.split("?")

console.log(s[1] );
```

Comment: This will give the wrong string.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz then how it should be ?

Comment: 1 instead of a 0.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz  ok.! right.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the part of the string you want in different ways

## Using indexOf and substring

```
var str = "www.medicoshere.com/register.html?23457cedlske234cd";
var partIndex = str.indexOf("?");
var part = str.substring(partIndex + 1); // 23457cedlske234cd
```

## Using Split

```
var part = str.split("?")[1];
```

The only problem is that, if you use `substring`, part will contain the whole string if the part you tried finding is not part of the string, say

```
var str = "www.medicoshere.com/register.html#23457cedlske234cd";
var partIndex = str.indexOf("?");
var part = str.substring(partIndex + 1); // www.medicoshere.com/register.html#23457cedlske234cd
```

while using split would return `undefined` as the value of part.