# Dynamic string split while binding data in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement [chips style](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_chips.asp).
Adding tags and remove tags like chips style to an item, for that I need to split string and bind separately based on length of array of split.

How to split comma speared dynamic length string while binding data.

**how can I use angular filters here**
Please check following code.

JS: Controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 
  var temp= {
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tags": "Design research, UI Frameworks, Wireframes" 
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": "Hockey, basketball, Cricket, Football, Baseball"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": "Sensors, maps, Location Service, Studio"      
    },
  ],
  "count": "3"
};
 // I have json like this
 $scope.items = temp.values; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller ="myCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span>{{item.tags}}</span>
  </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- here  I am trying implement chips style -->
  <!-- Requieremrnt-->
  <span style="background:#ddd;">{{item.tags[0]}}</span>
   <span style="background:#ddd;">{{item.tags[1]}}</span>
  <span style="background:#ddd;">{{item.tags[n]}}</span>
  <!-- can I use ng-repeat or custom filter. if yes how??--> 
  <hr>
  </body>
```

Can I use ng-repeat or custom filter. if yes how??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your snippet to have complete, runnable code?

Comment: working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a custom filter to do so ([although you can if you want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448100/how-to-split-a-string-with-angularjs)).

For this particular purpose, you can split the `tags` in your controller and then simply iterate through the strings in your view. In this case we'll use a double `ng-repeat`. The first one to iterate through all group of strings in each set of `tags` and the second one to iterate through the split string items. I've modified your code below and cleaned it up a bit.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var temp= {
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tags": "Design research, UI Frameworks, Wireframes" 
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": "Hockey, basketball, Cricket, Football, Baseball"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "tags": "Sensors, maps, Location Service, Studio"      
    },
  ],
  "count": "3"
};
                       
 $scope.items = temp.values.map(function (item) {
  return item.tags.split(",");
 });
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" >
  <div ng-controller ="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="group in items">
      <p ng-repeat="tag in group">{{tag}}</p>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```