# How to add a line break in ASP.NET Boilerplate menu from Navigation Provider with localization

Tags: c#, angularjs, line-breaks, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have defined menu items using the Navigation Provider with localization. How can I add a line break in the middle of the menu name?

**Navigation Provider**

```
public override void SetNavigation(INavigationProviderContext context)
    {
        context.Manager.MainMenu
            .AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    "Menu Item",
                    new LocalizableString("MenuItem", MyAppConsts.LocalizationSourceName),
                    url: "#/menuitem",
                    icon: "fa fa-clipboard"
                    )
            );
    }
```

**My Localization Source File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <localizationDictionary culture="en">
      <texts>
        <text name="MenuItem" value="Menu Item" />
      </texts>
    </localizationDictionary>
```

**cshtml file where the menu is created**

```html
<div class="sidebar-inner">

            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li ng-repeat="menuItem in vm.menu.items" ng-class="{active: vm.currentMenuName == menuItem.name}" class="nav-parent">
                        <a ng-if="!menuItem.items.length" ng-href="{{menuItem.url}}"><i class="{{menuItem.icon}}" ng-if="menuItem.icon"></i><span>{{menuItem.displayName}}</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <a ng-if="menuItem.items.length" href="" ><i class="{{menuItem.icon}}" ng-if="menuItem.icon"></i><span>{{menuItem.displayName}}</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        
                        <ul ng-if="menuItem.items.length" class="children collapse">
                            <li ng-repeat="menuSubItem in menuItem.items">
                                <a ng-href="{{menuSubItem.url}}"><span>{{menuSubItem.displayName}}</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
 </div>
```

I want it shown like

```
 Menu
 Item
```

Not like this

```
Menu Item
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try using css ?  Is there any specific reason why you dont want to use css ?

Comment: You must change the partial view

Comment: How can I do that. Can you please explain more? @isaeid

Comment: If you using abp templates there is a view for navigation component in `Views\Shared\Components\SideBarNav` you can get help from it.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari Because in the ASP.NET Boilerplate template I can use the in built menu?

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry, i think i did not understand you correctly, you want to show an menu item in two lines. if you want that. it is possible to change " " in "menu item" in show time to "<br />". Is not responsive to you?

Comment: No that doesn't work for me because I'm supposed to pass the display name of the menu from the XML source file in `<text value = " " />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out using string split. In the XML source I have added a '$' where I want to break the menu name into two lines.

```
<texts>
    <text name="MenuItem1" value="Long$Name" />
    <text name="MenuItem2" value="Short Name" />
</texts>
```

Then I used string split to break the menu display name into two and displayed it in two lines with 
 tag.

```html
<a ng-if="!menuItem.items.length" ng-href="{{menuItem.url}}">
       <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}" ng-if="menuItem.icon"></i>
       <span>
          {{menuItem.displayName.split('$')[0]}} <br> {{menuItem.displayName.split('$')[1]}}
       </span><span class="fa arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add an split filter to angular, and change your code to:

```
<span>{{menuSubItem.displayName | split:' ':0}}<br /> {{menuSubItem.displayName | split:' ':1}}</span>
```

See [How to split a string with angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448100/how-to-split-a-string-with-angularjs/29669232) to how to add split filter.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using split is the answer. Now it's working fine but I want to chose the menu items which I need to display in two lines.

Comment: Angular has if-else. try use it in span.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the file i said in comments, there is an ul-li tags to creating menu, which means you can change the view decoration with css.If you using bootstrap simply change `<div class="menu">` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` and change `<ul class="list">` to `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`.

Comment: Sorry I can not find the file you said SideBarNav. I have edited my question with the menu definition.

Comment: Sorry, SideBarNav is a folder wich contains a viewcomponent to create a side bar navigation. In that viewcomponent we can see an implementation of navigator with abp's system.